# If $(x_{n}) \rightarrow x$, show that $\sqrt{x_{n}} \to \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

If $(x_{n}) \rightarrow x$, show that $\sqrt{x_{n}}  \rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ for $x > 0$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, want to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x_{n}} - \sqrt{x}| < \epsilon$.

$$|\sqrt{x_{n}} - \sqrt{x}| = | \sqrt{x_{n}} - \sqrt{x}| \cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt{x_{n}} + \sqrt{x} }{\sqrt{x_{n}} + \sqrt{x}}\right) = \frac{|x_{n} - x|}{\sqrt{x_{n}} + \sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{|x_{n} - x|}{\sqrt{x}}  < \epsilon.$$

So choose $N$ such that $|x_{n} - x| < \epsilon \sqrt{x}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, your proof is correct. Some people would argue that the line

> Choose $N$ such that $\vert x_n-x\vert <\epsilon\sqrt x$.

requires some extra explanation on why such an $N$ exists. This is of course due to the fact that $(x_n)\to x$.